# What does "stack" mean, not as in push/pop but as in "the software stack"

Tags: stack

I often see this work "stack" being used in a different context than I'm familiar to. I know stack as in, a dynamic last-in-first-out list that you can push and pop things on and off. Even with a dedicated stack pointer CPU register back in the old days of assembler programming.

But now I often see people talking about their "software stack" (referring to, I don't know, their entire code base?) or "the Android stack" or "the Microsoft stack". I get a rough feeling for what that means, but I can't seem to find a clear, conclusive definition. Anyone?

Comment: Do a google search for "software stack". The first page of results has several definitions, e.g. http://www.techopedia.com/definition/27268/software-stack .

Comment: Thanks everybody for the extensive answers!

Answer (score 3):

Software stacks are considered as such because they usually tend to pile a few layers of abstraction onto one another.

For example "the Microsoft stack" would be something like this:

- one of the available languages (say C#)
- using some version of .NET
- which runs on some version of the CLR
- which runs on some version of Windows

Arguably, the software stack continues further, if you consider the tooling to be part of it, so maybe some version of Visual Studio or whatever kind of IDE and interface builder and build tool and whatever you are using.

Others have mentioned the LAMP stack, which also is a stack where

- you write PHP
- which uses MySQL and is invoked by Apache
- which run on Linux

Most of the time, you live on top of the stack, where life is pleasant. For example you can use C# without having to know much about the CLR (although you're better off knowing it) or deal with how .NET is implemented or having to make kernel calls directly. In PHP you will also not have to interface with the MySQL server by hand (open socket, write command, read answer, deserialize etc.). In fact if your stack includes a framework such as [Symfony](http://symfony.com/), you will not even deal with SQL most of the time, as the framework deals with that.

Answer (score 2):

It usually refers to the combination of programs being used to achieve a particular purpose.

A popular use of the term is LAMP stack which refers to:

- Linux
- Apache
- MySQL
- PHP

Answer (score 2):

we will be having many  types of stack's in case of computers they are

**Call stack**: stack data structure that stores information about the active subroutines of a computer program.
Stack-based memory allocation.

**Stacks (software)**: a folder view on the Dock of Mac OS X.

**Protocol stack:** a particular software implementation of a computer networking protocol suite.

**Solution stack**: a group of software systems, increasing in abstraction from bottom to top.

Answer (score 1):

it means : what combination of development environments do you use?

common example : [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29/%22LAMP%22)

personal example : I use R, SAS, Python and Hadoop

Answer (score 1):

I think I get what your are trying to ask. When I come across "stack" outside of the data-structure it is usually a reference to a particular software ecosystem. For instance you may need program A and program B to run program C. Basically software that function together for a specific result/outcome. I am not sure if you were looking for this type of high level definition, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

A "software stack" is a general term used to reference a set of mainstream technologies, that, when used together, can accomplish a complete software system (e.g. UI, services, logic, and persistence), usually on a particular OS (e.g. `Windows`, `Linux`) and / or runtime (`JVM`, `CLR`, `javascript` etc).

For example, a common "Microsoft Web Stack" might comprise `jQuery` (or `Angular.js`), `ASP.Net MVC`, `ASP.Net Web API`, `C#`, `Entity Framework`, and a relational database such as `Sql Server`.

Other stacks include [MEAN](http://mean.io/#!/) and "LAMP" etc

Similarly, this leads to the term `Full Stack Developer` viz, a developer who has competence in all the technologies of a particular stack, i.e. one who, in a particular Software Stack, can build any layer or build a complete system.

And not to be confused with a [Full StackOverflow Developer :)](https://www.christianheilmann.com/2015/07/17/the-full-stackoverflow-developer/)